# How to build an efficient micro-services architecture while paying attention to single responsibility, when authorizing?

Tags: jwt, authorization, microservices

Let's say I have an **Authorisation-Service** and I need to support multiple user roles.

And let's say I want to restrict access to different *routes* from **XY-Service** based on the user roles. I can think only of two options:

1) Send a request to the **Authorisation-Service**, which will decide if I'm authorised or not. This is clearly not efficient, as I have to communicate with the Authorisation Service multiple times.

2) Use *JWT*, get the user role and decide in **XY-Service** if the user is authorised or not to access that resource/route. This is more efficient, but introduces authorisation logic in a microservice, that shouldn't deal with this kind of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of JWT is a widely spread practice and does not violate the principle of unique responsibility because the principle of unique responsibility refers to non-technical "functional" responsibility (bussiness logic), your microservice functionally does one thing and technically many: logging, security, tracing...
Currently there is a strong tendency to move all those technical features out of the business development itself by using envoy/istio

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement Netflix Zuul as an API gateway. This provides various filters which can be used for your specific purposes especially verification and routing.
Zuul api gateway is easy to implement through spring boot.